# Image as bullet point is not displayed in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have a list containing different statements. Each statement should have an individual image as a bullet point. No image is shown as a bullet point, but the normal "disc" ones.

```css
/* I tried different approaches like:
 */

#boxes .search li {
  list-style-image: url('./img/icons/search.svg')
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
  <div class="advantages">
    <ul id="search">
      <li>My statement, which should display "search" as a bullet image</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="time">
      <li>My statement, which should display "time" as a bullet image</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="open_folder">
      <li>My statement, which should display "a folder" as a bullet image</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="shake">
      <li>My statement, which should display "a handshake" as a bullet image</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have search as id in HTML, in CSS as class reference. Change one of the two.

Comment: `list-style-image` is a setting of `ul` not `li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
#boxes li{
  background-image: url('./img/icons/search.svg')
}
```

*EDIT* from comments it sounds like you want :

```
#search {
   background-image: url('./img/icons/search.svg')
}
```

Comment: This will apply the search image to every bullet point in the list, not just the search one.

Comment: if u want the search one then just do that selector, i dont get what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semi-colon in the css code. here's the working code-

```
#boxes ul#search li{
  list-style-image: url('http://css-plus.com/examples/2011/12/custom-list-style/i/tick.png');
}
```

OR

```
#boxes #search li{
  list-style-image: url('http://css-plus.com/examples/2011/12/custom-list-style/i/tick.png');
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/g747DzzOqe